# Automapper - exclude some objects from mapped collection

Tags: c#, collections, mapping, automapper, automapper-6

I have the following map rules:

```
CreateMap<ViewModels.ApplicationDriverAccidentFormVM, ApplicationDriverAccidentDomain>();
```

then I want to map ViewModels.ApplicationDriverFormVM to ApplicationDriverDomain, both are have Accidents property, which are appropriate collections for each type.

```
public class ApplicationDriverDomain
{
    public List<ApplicationDriverAccidentDomain> Accidents { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDriverFormVM
{
    public List<ApplicationDriverAccidentFormVM> Accidents { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to exclude (not map) all records, which are not satisfied some conditions
I try to write the following code:

```
        CreateMap<ViewModels.ApplicationDriverFormVM, ApplicationDriverDomain>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Accidents, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetNotNullFromCollection(src.Accidents)))
```

where GetNotNullFromCollection is:

```
    List<object> GetNotNullFromCollection(object input)
    {
        List<object> output = new List<object>();
        foreach (var item in (List<object>)input)
        {
            if (!Utils.IsAllNull(item))
                output.Add(item);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

but it says me:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Web.ViewModels.ApplicationDriverAccidentFormVM]'
>   to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'.

Why and how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by the following way:

```
CreateMap<ViewModels.ApplicationDriverFormVM, ApplicationDriverDomain>().ForMember(dest => dest.Accidents, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Accidents.Where(o => !Utils.IsAllNull(o))))
```

Answer (score 0):

your method `GetNotNullFromCollection` receives an object but you are passing it a list.
Anyway, I would recommend using [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) instead of objects.

Comment: List<T> is not an object?

Comment: List<T> is a list of a generic type, not an object. Please read more about the subject of Generics